# What kind of encryption is this? How to decode?

Tags: encryption, encoding, base64

```
VX6qCjRCiNzT6eM3BnPWLQ==
NGiF1LGiWl/OZF5DgMJG7g==
KLDihwa/QoAli1fXGRBE+w==
xNIq8fEgPrqiAvh0enafFQ==
Y1Xl0Dnhg/my+f7B7E8bTw==
VwKubU/H0eiUGRI1y8RdoQ==
+Nq4BpYgRcAtaIsd4r59YA==
g/xBUl0cOVVgf6uySxGlyg==
B9uRZux05vdfjFiIlDen1g==
TK/TTvTSUW+Tbm8lYmZQpA==
iZmYYSnFGBKv4paJTDOsWQ==
```

I think it's base64 encoding.

Is there a way to decrypt it?

Comment: Please read the [help] and [ask] before posting again.  Also note that, if they were encrypted, there would be nothing you could do without the encryption key.  You have no good reason to believe (based on the information you've given us) that they are encrypted, however.

Comment: Questions of this form, that basically ask "what is this random data" without adequate context are not programming questions and are always off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is Base64 decoding. You can decode by running through base64:

```
$ echo VX6qCjRCiNzT6eM3BnPWLQ== | base64 -D | xxd
00000000: 557e aa0a 3442 88dc d3e9 e337 0673 d62d  U~..4B.....7.s.-
```

Comment: But it does not work.

Comment: What do you mean "does not work?" That's the decoding of the Base64-encoded string you gave.

Comment: ex) ZPeQndEZZQ2LEkWd3787Uw== This is original 138684zxx but echo ZPeQndEZZQ2LEkWd3787Uw== | base64 --decode result E;S

Comment: If you know what these values are, what is your question? The string "ZPeQndEZZQ2LEkWd3787Uw==" is the base64-encoding of 64f7 909d d119 650d 8b12 459d dfbf 3b53, not "138684zxx." It seems you have a completely different question than the one you asked.

Comment: I wonder if I can decode what I do not know.

Comment: If you are reverse engineering something, then this is not the right forum. There is no forum I know of that will let you post random data and reliably answer "what is this?" But if you want to learn more about reverse engineering, you can start at a site like https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com.

Comment: If you're not reverse engineering something, then please provide the code you're asking about. 16 random bytes don't mean anything.